# How to declare `dispatch_function_t` for `dispatch_async_f` in Swift?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Xcode 7 beta 5. I'm attempting to use `dispatch_async_f` to avoid a block.

```
func myFirstFunc() {
    let identifier = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(identifier, 0)
    let context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
    let work: dispatch_function_t = myOtherFunc
    dispatch_async_f(queue, context, work)
}
func myOtherFunc(context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
}
```

Got an error:

> A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func'
>   or a literal closure

Comment: You obviously could just use block to call `myFirstFunc`, e.g. `dispatch_async(queue) { self.myOtherFunc() }`.

Comment: I thought I could easily avoid a block. Apparently it is not that easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `myOtherFunc` is a method of a class, is that right? This will only work if `myOtherFunc` is declared as a free function at the top level.

Comment: Oh, can't use class methods? So sad. Then I guess it's better to use a block if I want a background use of `self`.